# Count matching phrase message Slackbot via Zapier

Tags: bots, slack, zapier

I am trying to create a Slackbot that responds to slash commands, counts the number of times a given phrase occurs in a certain channel after a certain date. I have successfully set up a Zapier pipeline that captures the request, formats a search, and returns a result. Something along the lines of:

```
in:#[channel] “[searchText]” after:[dd/mm/yyyy]
```

It seems that Zapier's Slack search integration can only return a single message. Is there a way to get the count of messages I am seeking through Zapier or an alternative approach.

I could do this through a python script but I want deliver response as a Slackbot. Zapier's code app states:

```
Unfortunately you cannot require external libraries or install libraries commonly referred to as "pip modules".
```

Which prevents me from writing a python snippet within Zapier as the code would need to use `slackclient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

[slackclient](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) is just a wrapper for their (quite full featured, IMO) API. To use its functionality, you've got a couple of options:

1. If you're comfortable writing javascript, create a [custom private app](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli) with a "search message and count" action. You can use the [slack JS sdk](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk) (since the CLI can use npm modules) or use the included `z.request` to write API code. Then you can return whatever data you'd like. If you go this route, you can get started with [the template](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-example-app-create).
2. If you want to stick with Python, you can use the request module ([docs here](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#weather-json-api-call)) to make the aforementioned Slack API calls yourself.

Hopefully that points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop your own logic: Here is how to count the occurrences of a phrase within a channel:

1. Retrieve all messages in a channel within a specific timeframe by calling the API method[`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history).
2. Go through all messages and count the ones that contain the phrase